# AudioWizard not working properly

Tags: windows-10, headphones, realtek-hd-audio

I have just installed Realtek Audio Driver 6.0.1.8564 x64 version and AudioWizard on Windows 10.

But none of the controls in AudioWizard, except Balance, seem to have any effect on my audio on my headphones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reinstalling your audio drivers